# Django inspectdb for Oracle

Tags: django, oracle, inspectdb

I am doing a project and need retrieve tables/models from a Oracle database(version 19c). So I am trying to use Django ‘inspectdb’ to do this.

– my settings.py looks like:

```
import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=“/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_7”)

DATABASES = {
‘default’: {
‘ENGINE’: ‘django.db.backends.oracle’,
‘NAME’: ‘service name’,
‘USER’: ‘XXX’,
‘PASSWORD’: ‘XXX’,
‘HOST’: ‘’,
‘PORT’: ‘’,
‘OPTIONS’: {
‘threaded’: True,
‘use_returning_into’: False,

 },
}
}
```

– Running these followings in shell are all good:

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(‘Host Name’, ‘Port Number’, service_name=‘Service Name’)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=‘User Name’, password=‘Personal Password’, dsn=dsn_tns)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(‘select * from schema.table’)

for row in c:
print (row)
```

Issues: But when I try using : `python3 manage.py inspectdb schema.table`

It returns error :
"The error was: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist "

Could anyone help me? thanks alot!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am running into the same issue.